# Ethernet stopped working suddenly on Orange Pi version of ubuntu jammy

Tags: ethernet, arm64

I use an orange pi zero 2 as a home server/media center
with the ubuntu jammy version released by orange pi.
(Orangepizero2_3.0.6_ubuntu_jammy_server_linux5.16.17)

A few weeks ago, my ethernet connection stopped working as I was watching a video stored on this server on my TV.

I would be very grateful if someone more experienced could give me some feedback.

I am a very basic linux user and I've tried a bunch of thing I found on various forums
throughout the internet. Unfortunately, I haven't been very successful so far.

I ended up burning again my sdcard for a fresh restart, and even that didn't get my ethernet to work. This is why I am starting to believe that the ethernet controller just burned after about 1 month of use.. :(

I am not even sure what command results would be relevant to be shown here, but
I am copying a couple of them below anyway.

Pif.

**ip addr:**

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 02:00:1c:80:72:be brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 7c:d0:00:a7:ff:48 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.2/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global noprefixroute wlan0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fd00::f3ae:8f96:6433:6d9c/64 scope global temporary dynamic
       valid_lft 603357sec preferred_lft 84427sec
    inet6 fd00::d91e:8502:a93d:8181/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute
       valid_lft 2591995sec preferred_lft 604795sec
    inet6 fe80::f360:4682:b70a:7bcd/64 scope link noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

**ifconfig:**

```
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 116  bytes 8892 (8.8 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 116  bytes 8892 (8.8 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.2  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fd00::f3ae:8f96:6433:6d9c  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fd00::d91e:8502:a93d:8181  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::f360:4682:b70a:7bcd  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 7c:d0:00:a7:ff:48  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 7367  bytes 4625448 (4.6 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 5690  bytes 1411392 (1.4 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

**ifconfig eth0**

```
eth0: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 02:00:1c:80:72:be  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 32
```

**sudo ethtool eth0**

```
netlink error: Device or resource busy
netlink error: Device or resource busy
netlink error: Device or resource busy
netlink error: Device or resource busy
netlink error: Device or resource busy
No data available
```

**sudo networkctl**

```
WARNING: systemd-networkd is not running, output will be incomplete.

IDX LINK  TYPE     OPERATIONAL SETUP
  1 lo    loopback n/a         unmanaged
  2 eth0  ether    n/a         unmanaged
  3 wlan0 wlan     n/a         unmanaged

3 links listed.
```

**cat /etc/network/interaces**

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*
# Network is managed by Network manager
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

**dmesg | grep eth0**

Gives a bunch of identical messages:

```
[   18.925658] dwmac-sun8i 5020000.ethernet eth0: no phy at addr -1
[   18.925683] dwmac-sun8i 5020000.ethernet eth0: stmmac_open: Cannot attach to PHY (error: -19)
```

**Trying to activate the connection with nmtui**

```
Could not activate connection:
Activation failed: the device could not be readied for configuration
```